# Вызов метода в другом классе

Tags: android, kotlin

Как в классе можно вызвать такой метод kotlin

```
fun Locale?.languageName(): String = this?.getDisplayLanguage(this)?.capitalize() ?: ""
```

Comment: А где вы его обьявили?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja объявил в классе LocaleTools

Comment: Отлично, меняем вопрос на лету, то надо из Java, теперь из Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
var text = Locale.getDefault().languageName()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я его обьявлю в пакете `com.example.Extentions`, то компилятор создаст там класс `ExtentionsKt` с этим методом как статическим.

Соответственно, из Java вызов будет таким:

```
String languageName = com.example.Extensions.ExtensionsKt.languageName(Locale.CANADA);
```

Comment: Уже даже сконвертировал класс в котлин и пробую вызывать примерно следующим образом ` val languageName = com.sai.android.utils.languageName(locale) ` но languageName по-прежнему unresolved

Comment: А кто сказал что он в Котлине так будет вызываться? :)

Comment: Изучайте матчасть https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Comment: Вроде как так `        var text = getLocale().languageName()
` но getLocale() всё равно unresolved reference(

Comment: Если правильно обьявить, все ресолвится. Разбирайтесь с областью видимости.